# Set value in Report Parameter (report viewer in remote mode)

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, ssrs-2008

I have already created a report in SSRS 2008. I'm using the Report Viewer to view it. I have one Report Parameter which is a list of usernames. I'd like to programatically select a particular value from that list.

So for instance, user: sdsmith goes to the page. The webpage will grab that username, check it against the list in ReportParameter1, then set the value of ReportParameter1 to sdsmith if it's found in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my previous post:

[Setting Report Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637464/set-reportviwers-parameter-in-an-application/637484#637484)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I had a complete misunderstanding of how this function worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you would be OK with creating a web page that would get the username, and then you could pass it as part of the URL to the actual report on the report server.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/de8b7774-a766-4454-a817-81cc19bab4a3

Comment: Well how would I pass that in the Report Viewer? I figured this had to be done through the API.